# Sync Firebase uploaded images with a PC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to make an app that has stores and users.

Each user belongs for a certain store and uploads images.
The store's need is to see a local directory that automatically syncs with the files that its users uploaded just like Dropbox/Google drive software does.

I found this tool: [Cloud File Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/cloud-file-explorer/9wzdncrdkv36).

But there are two problems with it:

1. Windows 8.1 as a minimum req is too high for the stores.
2. I'm not sure how would it be possible that the stores will see only their directory and not other store's directories.

Isn't it possible to just move/copy the files that users upload into Firebase to the store's Google drive / Dropbox account?

Answer (score 1):

As [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) makes use of [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), you can use either the [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) or the [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to directly download a user's images (aka Google Cloud Storage objects) to a local folder via your client application.

To separate images into different 'stores', simply append a 'store name/image.jpg' [sub-directory](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#object-considerations) (aka [Firebase reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files)) to your images when saving them, and then download all images from a single sub-directory 'store' by first [list them all](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-buckets#list-contents) using the Client Library.

As both Dropbox and Google Drive are separate systems from Google Cloud, you would need to use the [Dropbox APIs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) and the [Google Drive APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/) to upload these images from your client app to Dropbox and Google Drive.

Note that Dropbox and Google Drive are not supported by Google Cloud and you would need to contact their support channels for further assistance if needed.